# Integral Test and Series Convergence

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha > 0 $.  Then for what values of $\alpha$ does the following series converge?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)[\ln(k+1)]^{\alpha}}$$  I believe the answer is the series converges if and only if $\alpha>1$.  I tried using the integral test by changing the integral to $$\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln(n+1)}\frac{1}{u^{\alpha}}.$$  Then I want to say by the integral test, this is a bounded sequence of integrals if $\alpha>1$  because by the p-test.  Am I allowed to do that even though the integral is not from $1$ to $n$ as it is in the hypothesis of the integral test?

Thanksss!

Comment: because in the integral test that we have proven, we just need to show that the sequence of integrals is bounded that are from 1 to n

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it was clumsily worded. Let's try again. The common statement of the integral test is like this: "Suppose $f: [1,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is a decreasing function. Then $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx < +\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) < +\infty$." Perhaps you should add the precise statement of the integral test you're working with?

Comment: Let ${a_k}$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers and suppose that the function $f:[1,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and monotonically decreasing and has the property that $f(k)=a_k$ for every index k.  Then the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$$ is convergent if and only if the sequence of integrals $${\int_{1}^{n}f(x)dx}$$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

First by a obvious change of index the series is
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k(\ln k)^\alpha}$$
and by the integral test this series is convergent if and only if the following integral is convergent

$$\alpha\ne1,\qquad\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^\alpha}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(\ln x)^{1-\alpha}\Bigg|_2^\infty<+\infty\iff\alpha>1 $$

The case $\alpha=1$ is done by the same way *(but the antiderivative is a bit different)* and gives a divergent series.

Comment: again the Cauchy condensation test seems to work lol ... cheers!! (+1)

Comment: ...saves the day!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the given sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)[\ln(k+1)]^{\alpha}}$$
We can use the integral test for convergence, and from it, we say that the above sum converges if and only if the following integral converges:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x+1)[\ln(x+1)]^{\alpha}}$$
If we substitute $x+1\to u$ in the above then we get
$$\int_2^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u[\ln(u)]^{\alpha}}$$
Now, we substitute $\ln u\to v\implies e^v=u$ hence getting the integral:
$$\int_{\ln 2}^{\infty}\frac{e^v\mathrm{d}v}{e^vv^{\alpha}}=\int_{\ln 2}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{v^{\alpha}}$$
which is a convergent integral $\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{>1}$.
Therefore, the original sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)[\ln(k+1)]^{\alpha}}$$
converges if we choose any real value of $\alpha>1$.